# Organize items within a container like flex-direction: column with 3 columns but unknown height

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, nuxt.js

So, I hope I get this right. Here is the jsfiddle I came up with so far https://jsfiddle.net/fymo97zn/7/

So, I have a `.page` element that has fixed height and width to fit on a A4 page.

Within this are 2 containers one `.units` has width 100% and a dynamic (unknown) height.

The second container contains multiple (1...n) `.upgrade` elements.

Now, I want to fill those unit elements in a 3 column ways but not from left to right but form top to bottom, like a newspaper, or just like `column-count: 3` would do, but filling the first column first.

The issue seems to be, that it does not know how to wrap because I don't know the height of `.units` and this not the available space for `.upgrades`.

Does anyone have an idea?

I'm working with nuxt and scss.

```css
.page {
  max-height: 400px;
  max-width: 400px;
  min-height: 400px;
  min-width: 400px;
  background-color: lime;
 
}

.units {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}


.rest {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.upgrade {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 28%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="units">
  
  </div>
  <div class="rest">
   <div class="upgrade"></div>
   <div class="upgrade"></div>
   <div class="upgrade"></div>
   <div class="upgrade"></div>
   <div class="upgrade"></div>
   <div class="upgrade"></div>
   <div class="upgrade"></div>
   <div class="upgrade"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Maybe it can be done with js?

Comment: what the issue with using column-count:3 ?

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/gup3ewq2/ ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif because this balances the rows. What I want is, that if I only have content to fit into one column, then only the most left column should be filled

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D I added the code snippet.